How to force deallocation memory mapping of a MappedByteBuffer in Java 11 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Cleaner
I'm currently migrating the application code from java 8 to java 11, previously we use the internal class "sun.misc.Cleaner" and now when my application run I got a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Cleaner.
When i google it i found that i should use java.lang.ref.Cleaner to do it the same way, but i want to be sure that this is the right approach as i read that it will necessite the activation of internal module in my jvm.
Could you help me please ?
* Clean a <code>MappedByteBuffer</code>. Method to call to delete memory of the file and free the resources
* @param pByteBuffer Buffer to clean
*/
private void freeByteBuffer(ByteBuffer pByteBuffer) {
    try {
          Method lCleanerMethod = pByteBuffer.getClass().getMethod("cleaner");
          lCleanerMethod.setAccessible(true);
          Method lCleanMethod = Class.forName("sun.misc.Cleaner").getMethod("clean");
          lCleanMethod.setAccessible(true);
          lCleanMethod.invoke(lCleanerMethod.invoke(pByteBuffer));
         } catch (Exception lEx) {
           logger.error(KernelError.FREE_MEM, idefixComponentName, lEx); 
        }
    }

I expected the code to work the same way as it is in the spec of the software

More likely you should consider Foreign Memory API in JDK22 using FileChannel.map => MemorySegment. The duplicate does not look helpful at all, probably more like the inadvisable / hacks described in How to close MappedByteBuffer, and see JDK-4724038.

It doesn't look like you're supposed to do anything at all special to clear a MappedByteBuffer.  Doing something with Cleaner would just slow things down

As @DuncG said, Java 22 solves this problem. You might say, but this is not available in Java 11, but why are you migrating to Java 11 instead of the most recent version? Because of the tenacious myth about older versions being more stable? Quite pointless if you have to resort to hacks like the one shown in the question for cleanup…

Actually the snippet of code is not my software it is a from Third-Party Application Maintenance contract, and the client does not want to do a big jump to the last version of java.
So we have to deal with that.
Thanks for your responses i remove MappedByteBuffer and will do a stress test to see if i don't have some memory exception or regression !

You may as well test with MappedByteBuffer but without the hack. The cleaner will run when the garbage collector detects that the buffer is unreachable. The hack is only for releasing the native memory earlier than that but it might be that this is never necessary.
